# Should there be a flag option for migrating posts to Hermeneutics.SE?

Tags: feature-request, flagging, migration

Just now I was attempting to flag a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/42061/21576) for migration to Hermeneutics.SE, but I found no option to do so.  After selecting Off-Topic > "This questions belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network," the only option is to move the post to Meta:

> [image: Migration flag options]

Shouldn't we have an option here saying "belongs on hermeneutics.stackexchange.com"?

Comment: Just to be clear (the linked answer doesn't say this specifically either unfortunately), there *is* a (generic) flagging option to cover this contingency and it is "in need of moderator intervention". In raising this flag, you need to specify that the flagged question should be migrated to BH.SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying [my criteria for evaluating migration paths](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/when-should-we-consider-adding-a-default-migration-path):

1. There's an [obvious overlap](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1817/38417) between Biblical Hermeneutics and Christianity. Both sites have clear topic spaces and Christianity is [getting good question flow](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).
2. In the last 90 days, [according to the stats](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats), 17 questions were migrated from Christianity to BH and none were rejected. To me, this is right on the boundary between creating the path and not. However, [same report on Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats) says 35% are rejected. This seems to be an instance of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202188/migration-stats-not-consistent-between-sites). Assuming 35% is correct, I'd argue that too many migrations are rejected along this path.
3. Given that I'm not certain the path will be well used, I'm inclined to wait on this migration path.

Moderators *can* migrate to any site on the network, so feel free to flag such questions (Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Other) for them to evaluate.

Comment: A number of the "rejections" are more complicated than plain poor judgment in migration. Some of them are cross-posts or other shenanigans we are just trying to clean up. In other words of the migrations that do happen I think the vast majority are legit. On the other hand mods are hand picking what to migrate and, based on the flags I see here on C.SE asking for migration, easily half of them are _not_ good migration candidates. Very few people have a handle on what makes something a good BH question. All that to say I too would be a little leery of making this an automatic route.

Comment: I second that. I know *this* site *very* well. I hardly know BH at all. But I still custom flag for migration sometimes. I think many of the users here are a lot like me.

Comment: I was unaware of the difference between a formal "migration path" (just get enough 3k+ users to approve it and it's migrated) and the moderator intervention option.  If "migration path" just meant auto-fill a suggestion to a moderator, like I thought it did, I'd be more in favor.  But these points are well-taken considering the higher chance of mistakes made by 3k users.

Comment: (cc: @Caleb) Right (as your meta.SE link indicates), that discrepancy is accounted for by those closed on BH as duplicates. The majority of those migrations Caleb and I engineered, *purposely* migrating + close-as-dupe rather than closing here, for (from my perspective anyway) the sake of leaving the re-direct path from C.SE. None of those can be attributed to the inappropriate judgement of the C.SE community. On the other hand, Caleb has *not* migrated all of those inappropriately so-flagged, so I think the more relevant statistic is probably only represented by his comment above.